# Undenfined local variable or method when the view call a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm trying give a "Welcome Message" to my users with that:

```
 #welcome_controller.rb
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
      def hi
        @current_user
        if (@current_user)
          @welr = '¡Bienvenido' + current_user + ' a nuestra web!' 
        else
          @weli = "¡Bienvenido invitado, no dude en registrarse!"
        end
      end
    end
 #hi.html.erb Only the call
    <%= hi %>
```

When I initialize my server the controller give me this message:

> undefined local variable or method `hi' for

I have tried many wways of repairing this but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article may help you :
[Ruby on Rails: Accessing Controller Methods from Your View](http://teachmetocode.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-accessing-controller-methods-from-your-view/)

Just write:

```
<% @controller.hi %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define hi as a `helper_method` in your controller. Something like

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :hi

  def hi
    # your stuff here...
  end
```

end

See http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method for more info

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you use controller methods. In Rails, methods defined on a controller are used to 'set up' the data needed for a particular view, or to handle a given request. They're not supposed to be called directly by a view.

For what you're trying to do, you need to add a helper method to `WelcomeHelper`. So, assuming you want `http://yourapp.dev/welcome/` to output the message above, this is what you'd need:

```
# app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Explicitly defining the `index` method is somewhat redundant, given
    # that you appear to have no other logic for this view. However, I have
    # included it for the sake of example.
  end
end    

# app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
<%= greeting %>

# app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
class WelcomeHelper
  # All methods in WelcomeHelper will be made available to any views
  # that are part of WelcomeController.
  def welcome
    if (@current_user)
      # You may need to change this to something like `@current_user.name`,
      # depending on what @current_user actually is.
      '¡Bienvenido' + @current_user + ' a nuestra web!' 
    else
      "¡Bienvenido invitado, no dude en registrarse!"
    end
  end
end
```